# How to make an object globally accessible in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a custom caching provider for my MVC application.  I will use this class to store/retrieve session data to an outside service (like memcached or Redis).

I would like to create the object instance once at application start so that I can reference the object from any controller, and only have to 'new up' the instance once.  I was thinking that I would instantiate the class in the Global.asax Application_Start method.  However, the instance does not seem to be accessible in any of the controllers.

What is the preferred way to instantiate and then access a (global) class in MVC?

Here is a copy of my 'simplified' class:

```
 public class PersistentSession : IPersistentSession
    {
        // prepare Dependency Injection
        public ICache cacheProvider { get; set; }

        public bool SetSessionValue(string key, string value)
        {
            return cacheProvider.PutToCache(key, value);
        }

        public bool SetSessionValue(string key, string value, TimeSpan expirationTimeSpan)
        {
            return cacheProvider.PutToCache(key, value, expirationTimeSpan);
        }

        public string FetchSessionValue(string key)
        {
            return cacheProvider.FetchFromCache(key);
        }
    }
```

I want to instantiate it one time so that I can access it from all controllers application wide, something like this:

```
 // setup PersistentSession object
 persistentSession = new PersistentSession();
 string memcachedAddress = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MemcachedAddress"].ToString();
 string memcachedPort = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MemcachedPort"].ToString();

 persistentSession.cacheProvider = new CacheProcessor.Memcached(memcachedAddress, memcachedPort);
```

Where/How in MVC should the object be instantiated to get global access from all controllers?

Comment: You mean, aside from a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?  (in which case, pursue [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection))

Comment: I'm just stuck getting the singleton working.  I know this should be stupid easy, but being new to MVC, I'm missing something about how to instantiate the singleton so that I can 'see' the class across my controllers.  I'm trying to avoid having to new up my class in each controller, and am not sure where to do it in MVC.  DI can follow shortly after that...

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on what ["static" means in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: You are right, I have my terms mixed up. The class may not be static, as I want to set the address of the Memcached (or Redis, or whatever) server at runtime.  I'll edit my post to be more clear.

Comment: "static" is not the same as "compile time constant".  Static data can be assigned at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the problem !!

all you have to do is to add (static) keyword to the definition of the methods of PersistentSession class:

```
public class PersistentSession : IPersistentSession
{
    // prepare Dependency Injection
    public static ICache cacheProvider { get; set; }

    public static bool SetSessionValue(string key, string value)
    {
        return cacheProvider.PutToCache(key, value);
    }

    public static bool SetSessionValue(string key, string value, TimeSpan expirationTimeSpan)
    {
        return cacheProvider.PutToCache(key, value, expirationTimeSpan);
    }

    public static string FetchSessionValue(string key)
    {
        return cacheProvider.FetchFromCache(key);
    }
}
```

. and you can access them using the following code from anywhere :

```
PersistentSession.SetSessionValue (key , value);
```

you can also add a static constructor to initialize any fields before accessing any member, and the constructor is called before a member of static class is accessed for the first time, so you can be sure that your class is set before being used.

```
public static PersistentSession ()
{
//Put your initializing code, for example:
cacheProvider = new CacheProvider();
}
```

Comment: The answer seemed to be just dropping the interface off of the static class.